# What is the definition of abstract nouns?

Tags: meaning, grammar

How do you define the word 'abstract' in 'abstract noun'? Why are 'whiteness', 'laughter', 'arrival' abstract nouns?

Comment: Did you look it up?

Comment: There are multiple definitions for abstraction hence why I don't understand.